# Pretty sure I'm over complicating my loops but unsure how to simplify

Tags: java, for-loop

As the title says I just need some help/advice on how I can simplify a part of my code. I get the output I want but it's obvious to see that the way I go about it is a bit excessive. What I'm trying to do in my program is pass the array

```
int [] myInches = {89,12,33,7,72,42,76,49,69,85,61,23};
```

Into my `buildFeetArray` method which just takes the array elements, divides them by 12 to get a new element value which is then put in a new array which is returned. Here is the method

```
 public static int[] buildFeetArray(int[] arrayParam) {
    int sum = 0;
    int lessthan1 = 0;
    int lessthan2 = 0;
    int lessthan3 = 0;
    int lessthan4 = 0;
    int lessthan5 = 0;
    int lessthan6 = 0;
    int lessthan7 = 0;
    int lessthan8 = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count < arrayParam.length; count++) {
        if (arrayParam[count] / 12 == 0) {
            lessthan1++;
        } else if (arrayParam[count] / 12 == 1) {
            lessthan2++;
        } else if (arrayParam[count] / 12 == 2) {
            lessthan3++;
        } else if (arrayParam[count] / 12 == 3) {
            lessthan4++;
        } else if (arrayParam[count] / 12 == 4) {
            lessthan5++;
        } else if (arrayParam[count] / 12 == 5) {
            lessthan6++;
        } else if (arrayParam[count] / 12 == 6) {
            lessthan7++;
        } else if (arrayParam[count] / 12 == 7) {
            lessthan8++;
        }
    }
    int[] newArray = {lessthan1, lessthan2, lessthan3, lessthan4, lessthan5, lessthan6, lessthan7, lessthan8};
    return newArray;
}
```

Ideally the output should be

```
int length = 8;
[0] = 1;
[1] = 2;
[2] = 1;
[3] = 1;
[4] = 1;
[5] = 2;
[6] = 2;
[7] = 2;
```

Which it is but there's definitely an easier way to go about it, if possible I'd like to avoid using lists and sticking with loops as I need practice with them. Thank you in advance for any advice/tips.

Comment: The code in your question does not match *at all* with the specification. I'm having a hard time understanding what the code does, to be honest, but it clearly does not do what you claim it does. Can you give a *precise* specification of what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: It looks like you're returning the amount of entries that have 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. feet, Which doesn't match what you're saying it does. Also the "lessThan" naming make no sense since `lessThan8` should be _all_ of the entries given your input.

Answer (score 21):

I wrote some pseudo-code for this, in which you have to just initialize an array and increment particular index of array when a certain condition matches:

```java
public static int [] buildFeetArray(int [] arrayParam) {
    int index;
    int [] lessthan = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    for (int count = 0; count < arrayParam.length; count++) {
        index = arrayParam[count]/12;
        if(index < 8 ) {
            lessthan[index]++;
        }
    }
    return lessthan;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You may want to use another array to store the result, e.g :

```
public static  int[] buildFeetArray(int [] arrayParam) {

    int[] lessThanArray = new int[8];

    for (int count = 0; count < arrayParam.length; count++) {
        for (int remainder = 0; remainder < lessThanArray.length; remainder++) {

            if (arrayParam[count] / 12 == remainder) {

                lessThanArray[remainder]++;
                break; // exit from the inner "for" loop
            }
        }
    }

    return lessThanArray;
}
```

Comment: Still there is really no reason to use a second loop for this; it only adds confusion.

Answer (score 10):

What about this:

```
int[] lessThanArray = new int[8];
for (int entry: myInches) {
    int lessThan = entry / 12;
    if (lessThan < 8) { 
        lessThanArray[lessThan]++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a Switch block:

```
switch(arrayParam[count]/12){
  case 0:
    lessthan1++;
    break;
  case 1:
    lessthan2++;
    break;
  //and so on...
}
```

The effect is the same but it looks way more clean and it comes in handy in situations such like this one

Answer (score 3):

We can use some Java-8 APIs to make it even shorter.

```
public static  int [] buildFeetArray(int [] arrayParam, int length) {
       int [] result = new int[arrayParam.length];
       IntStream.range(0, arrayParam.length).forEach(i -> result[arrayParam[i] / 12] = result[arrayParam[i] / 12] + 1 );
       return Arrays.copyOf(result, length);
 }
```

**Explanation**:

- Make a temp array
- Iterate through a integer stream generating index values till the length of the input array.
- In each iteration, find the index as the result of the division with 12 and increment it the count, i.e. `89/12 = 7` so the the 7<sup>th</sup> index's count is incremented. This would denote `lessthan8` variable in your code.
- Return an array of the desired length by passing an additional `length` parameter.

Input:

```
int[] res = buildFeetArray(new int[]{89,12,33,7,72,42,76,49,69,85,61,23}, 8);
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

I simply modified your code a little. You may try this:

```java
public static  int [] buildFeetArray(int [] arrayParam) {
    int sum = 0;
    int len=8; // your ideal lengh, change it if needed
    int[] lessthan = new int[len+1];
    for(int i=0; i<len+1; i++){ lessthan[i]=0; }

    for (int count = 0; count < arrayParam.length; count++) {
        int d = arrayParam[count]/12;
        d = d+1; 
        lessthan[d]++;
        // so, if arrayParam[count]/12 == 0,1,2,..., then d = 1,2,3,...  
        
    }
    return lessthan;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is technically incorrect please read the question thoroughly again